How to select and display one particular graphic from a small number of given locations
\documentclass[english,11pt,twosided,openright]{book}%
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}%
\usepackage{xcolor} %
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=170mm,asymmetric,marginparsep=0pt,margin=0mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm, % 240mm
left=12.5mm,right=12.5mm,top=0mm,showcrop,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} %
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\usepackage{theoremref}%
\usepackage{refcount}%

\graphicspath{D:/TeX_LaTeX}

\newcounter{acounter}
\newcommand{\testroutine}

\renewcommand{\testroutine}
{
        \ifnum {#1=1}
{\includegraphics[scale=1.00]{../math_text/front_rear_spine_figs/colour_code_vol_01}}\relax
        \else
        \ifnum {#1=2}
{\includegraphics[scale=1.00]{../math_text/front_rear_spine_figs/colour_code_vol_02}}\relax
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]\centering % this direct call works when the test routine is commented out.
\includegraphics[scale=1.00]{../math_text/front_rear_spine_figs/colour_code_vol_01}
\end{figure}

\setcounter{acounter}{1}

\begin{figure}[htp]\centering % this selective call fails
\testroutine{acounter}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


your question appears unrelated to graphics, \ifnum {#1=1} is a syntax error you can not have {} there. and you open two \ifnum that you never close with \fi

also, unrelated to your question, depending on the back end [scale=1.00] night be a relatively expensive way of doing nothing, better to omit the argument in that case.

to use \ifnum with a latex counter, you also need \value{} either in the argument or in the test e.g. \ifnum\value{#1}=1 one\else\ifnum\value{#1}=2 two\fi\fi. (provided you define the command to take an argument etc. too.)

Your code comment suggests that you get an error on the the call on line 37 but that is not the case, your example stops much earlier on the defintion
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \testroutine.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.27     }

as you use #1 in a definition of a command with no arguments.
If you use
\renewcommand{\testroutine}[1]

You get further but
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.38 \testroutine{acounter}
                           
? 

which is due to the syntax error

        \ifnum {#1=1}

the tex primitive requires a number not a { and also must have a matching \fi to close the \if
so you could use
\renewcommand{\testroutine}[1]
{%
        \ifnum \value{#1}=1
      \includegraphics{../math_text/front_rear_spine_figs/colour_code_vol_01}%
        \else
        \ifnum \value{#1}=2
       \includegraphics{../math_text/front_rear_spine_figs/colour_code_vol_02}%
\fi
\fi
    }

But simpler would be
\renewcommand{\testroutine}[1]{%
\includegraphics{../math_text/front_rear_spine_figs/colour_code_vol_0\arabic{#1}}}


@cfr oh sigh OP used a latex counter yes thanks I'll fix, thanks

@cfr done thanks

sorry ;) ......

Many thanks to you all.  For one thing, I would never have thought one could interfere with (part of) a file name.  Leaving out [scale=1.00], is that significant? - I have hundreds of those!

@keith77777 it is like doing \scalebox{1}{foo} instead of foo  it is slower as the argument has to be parsed it also makes the pdf bigger as the scaling commands are inserted into the pdf stream, and it has no visible effect.

`Thanks, fortunately, removing them from the text file is easy.
